# Create view onLongPress and then handle onTouchEvent of the newly created view

Tags: android

I have a following layout

- parent view
- -- child view
- -- child view
- -- child view
- -- child view

All of these are highly customized views, therefore startDrag won't work here (I rather move corners of the child views than move them). The parent view is not exactly a layout containing all those children, but a separate view.

Now, `onLongClick` on the parent view, I create a new child view, just where the user longClicked. And when the new view is created, I would like to handle the touch event inside the child view. **But I have to release the finger and touch the child view again for it to work.**

The desired flow of events:

- I long click the parent view and hold my finger,
- I still hold the finger on the screen - the child view is created
- still holding the finger on the screen, moving it, **I'd like to hanadle that touch event inside the child view**

I think I have to propagate the touch event to the child view or start the touch event inside of it programatically. But how to do it?

Comment: Is there a reason for wanting to handle the touch at the child view level and not within the parent(as the drag action is tied to the parent)?

Comment: @Luksprog It's a "frame" view which can be moved and resized based on where the user touched it (center, border, corner etc). The code which drags and resizes it is inside the view (also because this view, when active, covers whole screen and the frame is actually a hole inside of it). A typical action is to touch the view to "activate" it and then drag, resize etc.